# <LinkedList> Program doesn't give the correct answer

Tags: c++

this is my lab and I work all of it. After long time of debugging, fixing errors, finally it can compile. But when it run, it didn't give me the correct answer. It just kept saying : did not find y (may be x was added) and it was 4 line with the same answer.
please look at my code and tell me why it didn't work.
Thanks a lot.
Here is my code:

**LinkedList.h:**

```
#ifndef _LINKED_LIST_
#define _LINKED_LIST_

#include <ostream>

class LinkedList
{
public:
    LinkedList();
    LinkedList(char ch);
    LinkedList(const LinkedList& List);
    ~LinkedList();

    void add(const char& ch);
    bool find(char ch);
    bool del(char ch);

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, LinkedList& list);
private:
    struct node
    {
    char item;
    node * next;
    };
    node * head;
    int size;
};

#endif // _LINKED_LIST_
```

**Linkedlist.cpp**

```
    #include "linkedlist.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <cassert>
    #include <cstring>
    using namespace std;

LinkedList::LinkedList() : head(NULL)
{
}

LinkedList::LinkedList(char ch):head(NULL)
{
    char currData;
    currData = ch;
    add(currData);
}

LinkedList::~LinkedList()
{
    node * curr = head;
    while(head)
    {
        curr = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = curr;
    }
}

LinkedList::LinkedList(const LinkedList& List)
{
    if(List.head == NULL) 
        head = NULL;
    else
    {
        //copy first node
        head = new node;
        assert(head != NULL);
        head->item = List.head->item;

        //copy the rest of the list
        node * destNode = head;             //points to the last node in new list
        node * srcNode = List.head->next;  //points to node in aList
        while(srcNode != NULL) //or while (srcNode)
        {
            destNode->next = new node;
            assert(destNode->next != NULL); //check allocation
            destNode = destNode->next;
            destNode->item = srcNode->item;

            srcNode = srcNode->next;
        }
        destNode->next = NULL;
    }       
}

ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, LinkedList& list)
{
    while(list.head)
    {
        out << list.head->item << endl;
        list.head = list.head->next;
    }

    return out;
}

void LinkedList::add(const char& ch)
{
    node * prev = NULL;
    node * curr = head;

    while (curr != NULL && curr->item < ch)
    {
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    if (curr && curr->item != ch)
    {
        node * newNode = new node;
        newNode->item = ch;
        newNode->next = NULL;

        newNode->next = curr;
        if (prev == NULL)
            head = newNode;
        else
            prev->next = newNode;
            size++;
    }
}

bool LinkedList::del(char ch)
{
    char a;
    node * prev = NULL;
    node * curr = head;
    while (curr)
    {
         a = curr->item;
        if ( a == ch)
        {
            if(!prev)
                head = curr->next;
            else
                prev->next = curr->next;
            delete curr;
            size--;
            return true;
        }
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    return false;
}

bool LinkedList::find(char ch)
{
char a;
    node * prev = NULL;
    node * curr = head;
    while (curr)
    {
         a = curr->item;
        if ( a == ch)
        {
            return true;
        }
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    return false;   
}
```

**app.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "linkedlist.h"

using namespace std;

void find(LinkedList& list, char ch)
{
    if (list.find(ch))
        cout << "found ";
    else
        cout << "did not find ";
    cout << ch << endl;
}

int main()
{
    LinkedList  list;

    list.add('x');
    list.add('y');
    list.add('z');
    cout << list;
    find(list, 'y');

    list.del('y');
    cout << list;
    find(list, 'y');

    list.del('x');
    cout << list;
    find(list, 'y');

    list.del('z');
    cout << list;
    find(list, 'y');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Debugging comes after compiling. Now is the time to use your debugger to discover where your logic is wrong.

Comment: i actually only know how to use break point in visual studio. It's seem like i fail to add a linked list or make a linked list.
can anyone check and fix my constructor please ?
I think hard as i could, but it still stuck in there

Comment: Better take a few minutes to learn how to use the debugger then, *to step through your code*. It's extremely obvious and easy and you have no future in programming until you do it.

Comment: Also, figure out how to *add watch variable* so you can see it.  Also, check out the F10 and F11 keys. Right clicking on a variable will provide more information.

Comment: Your << modifies the list, which is never a good thing. The parameter should be const.

Comment: thank yous guys....
the  << it's surely wrong, i'll fix it.
and after i debug it....(kinda), i know my problem is that i can't make the link list, or constructor is wrong.
add function, i check it, and it's fine.
still working on it, any suggestion to fix the constructor ?

Comment: thank you guys so much. 
as you guys said, debugger is easy. 
after i do it in correct way, the problem was solved.

The first problem is <<, which is i will fix it later
The major problem is in the Add function.

Answer (score 0):

Your add method doesn't work, if the item to insert goes at the end it is not inserted (because you are checking for curr == NULL before inserting). Since head is set to NULL when you create the list if(curr && ...) won't ever be true and no item will be inserted.

Comment: thanks very much
i just figure it out few mins agon :D

you have my upvote :D

Comment: Thanks, but please learn to think/analyse by yourself, and format code correctly.